# Using If Statements To Check If Something Raises An Error

Tags: python, math, parametric-equations

I'm trying to write a program that will solve questions about parametric equations for me. I'm trying to do the following:

I'm trying to find 2 answers to a parametric equation. The first answer will be the positive square root. The second answer will be the negative square root. If the first square root raises a math domain error, don't find the second answer. This is what I have so far:

```
def hitsGround(vertical_velocity, y_coordinate):
    h = vertical_velocity/-16/-2
    k = -16*(h)**2 + vertical_velocity*(h) + y_coordinate
    time = float(input("At what height do you want me to solve for time?: "))
    try:
        hits_height1 = math.sqrt((time - k)/-16) + h
    except ValueError:
        print("It won't reach this height.")
    else:
        print(f"It will take {hits_height1} seconds to hit said height.")

    try:
        hits_height2 = -math.sqrt((time - k)/16) + h
    except ValueError:
        print("There is no second time it will reach this height.")
    else:     
        print(f"It will take {hits_height2} seconds to hit said height.")
```

Is there any way to use an if statement to check if the first equation raises a math domain error so I can make it so it doesn't find the second answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot test for a run-time exception with `if`; that's exactly what `try-except` does.  However, when the illegal operation is so directly defined, you can test for *that* condition before you try the `sqrt` opertaion:

```
if (time - k)/-16 < 0:
    # no roots
else:
    # proceed to find roots.
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the way to make exception handling easier to is to do everything you need to do to handle the exception within the `except`.  For example, if you don't want to find the second answer after you hit the first exception, just `return`:

```
    try:
        hits_height1 = math.sqrt((time - k)/-16) + h
    except ValueError:
        print("It won't reach this height.")
        return

    print(f"It will take {hits_height1} seconds to hit said height.")
```

If you want to make life even easier, just allow the exception to raise (without catching it at all), and catch it in the calling function!

```
def hitsGround(vertical_velocity, y_coordinate):
    h = vertical_velocity/-16/-2
    k = -16*(h)**2 + vertical_velocity*(h) + y_coordinate
    time = float(input("At what height do you want me to solve for time?: "))

    hits_height1 = math.sqrt((time - k)/-16) + h
    print(f"It will take {hits_height1} seconds to hit said height.")

    hits_height2 = -math.sqrt((time - k)/16) + h
    print(f"It will take {hits_height2} seconds to hit said height.")

try:
    hitGround(1.0, 10.0)
except ValueError:
    print("It won't reach that height again.")
```

Wherever the exception is raised in `hitsGround`, it will immediately stop whatever that function is doing, and it will hit the `except` in the calling scope.  That way you only need a single `try/except` to cover both cases.